# Cannot capture serialized textarea value

Tags: jquery, ajax

This code is working fine to capture `input` and `select` element values. However the `textarea` could not be captured. Does anyone know what is wrong and how to correct it?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $(".update_row_data").change(function() {
    action = $(this).closest('tr').data('action');
    form_data = $(this).closest('tr').find('input,select,textarea').serialize();
    console.log(form_data);

    $.ajax({
      data: {
        //Use that action name in ajax request.
        action: action,
        form_data: form_data,
      },
      url: 'updates_ok.php',
      type: 'post',
      beforeSend: function() {},
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == 1) {
          alert('update sucessful')
        }
      }
    });
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" align="center" style="table-layout:fixed">
  <tbody id="_editable_table">
    <tr data-action="update_data">
      <td>
        <input name="country" size="6" style="border-style:none" type="text" class="update_row_data country" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="city" size="8" style="border-style:none" class="update_row_data city"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The content of the `city` textarea is included in the serialised data, as you can see from the `console.log()` I added to the snippet in your question. Why do you believe it is not?

Comment: ok, i see, then the problem is the value cannot be sent now..., do you have any idea why only input and select element can be sent?

Comment: I am certain the values are sent. The issue is more likely to be in your `updates_ok.php` page. You can verify the content of the request by checking the network tab of dev tools

Comment: but it is working fine when I change to input tab, like

<input style="border-style:none" type="text" name="city" class="update_row_data city" value="">

Comment: thanks for spending your time, I realize that there is another input element for city in the same page, so even I make change for the textarea, but the other will overwrite it. I have delete the other one and it is working now, thanks again